# How to save Current page and Filter state in MVC?

Tags: c#, blazor, session-state

What's the issue:

I have two pages main page and details page.
For Example: in main page 4 if I apply filter and go into details page to check something, and click "Return back to main" button it is taking me back to page 1 with applied filter instead of 4.
Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Is this Blazor or MVC?  What have you tried?